# how to unregister an object in a managedObjectcontext?

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmanagedobject

Is there any method to do this job? I could not find in the document.

Comment: What are you asking? This does not make any sense.

Comment: Do you want to delete an object?

Comment: i think the method is deleteObject, thx all:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete an object from database use the following method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:[userResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [userResults removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // Save the context.
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

}

Where userResults is the NSMutableArray type, which you use to fetch data and store temporary values

Answer (score 0):

If you mean deleting you can use `[context deleteObject:object]` where `context` is your `NSManagedContext` and `object` is your `NSManagedObject` derived object.